# How do I update a web app to change in mysql db?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, web-applications

I want to alert a number of connected users to a change in the database without having the end user polling mysql. Is there a way to trigger a client update from the server side without moving long polling down the stack? 
I'm using PHP, Javascript, and MySQL. ~70 clients need to be updated at once and was hoping to have a better response time and lower hits to the web and db server than AJAX/COMET allows.

Thanks,

T

Comment: "Is there a way to trigger a client update from the server side?" AFAIK no. The ~70 clients (I believe you meant ~70 opened browsers using your software) must keep asking the server for any updates.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes, ~70 open browsers. I figured this would be the case but wanted to dream a little dream. It seems we will need to create a middle-ware server to handle browser communication and db updates.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [HTML5 web sockets](http://robertnyman.com/2010/10/22/introducing-html5-web-sockets-taking-bidirectional-communication-on-the-web-to-the-next-level-2/) too which would be a little more resource efficient than tons of Ajax calls.

Comment: unfortunately, this may not work in a "real world", where not every browser supports that. But if you can have configuration management and apply a HTML5 browser (like chrome) as a requirement for your users, then you have it! :)